# Change CSV before importing it to pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, quotes, double-quotes

I have an issue with a CSV files I am trying to import in pandas. The structure of the file is as follow:

- first character of the file is a single quote;
- last character of the file is a single quote;
- every line of the CSV start with a double quotes, end with a double quote followed by \n

So I have issues importing it with `pandas.read_csv`. Ideally I would like pandas to just ignore the single and double quotes when importing (not taking them into account for the structure of the data frame, and not importing these as characters).

I do not really know if I should manipulate the CSV file before using `pandas.read_csv`, or if I have option for just ignoring these characters.

Comment: Include sample file and the code that you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter 'quoting' and pass value 3 to [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). once you have dataframe created you should take care of the quotes in data and headers.

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.read_csv('check.txt',doublequote=True,delimiter=',',quoting=3)
df=df.replace({'"': '','\'':''}, regex=True)
df.columns = ['Id1','StartTime','start_lat','start_long','StartGeohash']

print df
```

Sample File

```
'Id1,StartTime,start_lat,start_long,StartGeohash
"113,2016-11-01 10:50:28.063,-33.139507,-100.226715,9vbsx2" 
"113,2016-11-02 10:49:24.063,-33.139507,-100.226715,9vbsx2" 
"115,2016-11-03 10:55:20.063,-36.197660,-101.186050,9y2jcm"'
```

output

```
   Id1                StartTime  start_lat  start_long StartGeohash
0  113  2016-11-01 10:50:28.063 -33.139507 -100.226715      9vbsx2 
1  113  2016-11-02 10:49:24.063 -33.139507 -100.226715      9vbsx2 
2  115  2016-11-03 10:55:20.063 -36.197660 -101.186050       9y2jcm
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. delimiter=',',quoting=3 are doing the trick for importing the file but I still have to deal with the double quotes on the values located in the first and last columns.

Comment: It should be noted this answer does not change the data *before* it is loaded, it changes it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The `pd.read_csv` methods first argument is either a file name or a stream.

You can read the file manually and manipulate the stream before handing it to pandas.

```
sio = StringIO("id,category,value\n1,beer,2.40\n2,wine,6.40\n3,$$$Theawsomestuff$$$###,166.00"
pd.read_csv(sio)
   id                 category  value
0   1                     beer    2.4
1   2                     wine    6.4
2   3  $$$Theawsomestuff$$$###  166.0
```

Thus subclassing StringIO you can change the behavior of the `read` method

```
class StreamChanger(StringIO):
    def read(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().read(**kwargs)
        data = data.replace("$", "")
        data = data.replace("#", "")
        return data

sio = StreamChanger("id,category,value\n1,beer,2.40\n2,wine,6.40\n3,$$$Theawsomestuff$$$###,166.00")
pd.read_csv(sio)
   id                 category  value
0   1                     beer    2.4
1   2                     wine    6.4
2   3           Theawsomestuff  166.0
```